# get selected item from the autocompete textbox suggestion in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a autocomplete text box where i want to do some function with the selected text. Now how can it get the selected item from the autocomplete text box suggestions???

I tried this events:

```
 private void kk_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void kk_DropDownClosed(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<bool> e)
    {

    }

    private void kk_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

but they are not exactly what i need. these events take action for several times when i select a item from the suggestion list.

Comment: Please specify which kind of operation you want to do on a selected item .. it will be more helpful to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use DropDownClosed and LostFocus event of AutocompeteBox. You can get Selected item on selection changed method. Here is the code.

```
private void kk_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{ 
if (e.AddedItems.Count == 0)
                return;
 var item= (cast as your type)e.AddedItems[0];
}
```